# receiving geoJSON polygon as POST in PHP not working in foreach

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, geojson

I have a google map page that user will use to outline an area. This will create a geoJSON polygon that is sent to a PHP page that receives the information and saves it with their user ID.

I seem to be sending the info using jQuery AJAX post to the php page fine. On the server page I use the following PHP to receive the jQuery post:

```
     $PlayerID=$_REQUEST['id'];
 $user_id=$_REQUEST['i'];
 $polygon=$_REQUEST['polygon'];


 $tempData = html_entity_decode($polygon);

 $json=json_decode($tempData, true);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($json);
 echo "</pre>";


 echo "ARRAY Stuff:<pre>";
 print_r($json->features);
 echo "</pre>";

 $set = 1;
 foreach($json->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[0] as $coordinates)
 {
     echo 'Set '.$set.': ';$set++;
     echo $coordinates[0].','.$coordinates[1]."<br>\n";
 }
```

The result is:

```
     <pre>{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
     {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [
           [
             [
               -79.5388860291992,
               43.97521723544242
             ],
             [
               -79.6542424745117,
               43.853534949336265
             ],
             [
               -79.4345159120117,
               43.854525239394725
             ],
             [
               -79.5388860291992,
               43.97521723544242
             ]
           ]
         ]
       },
       "properties": {}
     }
   ]
 }</pre>ARRAY Stuff:<pre></pre><br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>savePolygon_ajax.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
```

I have tried to call specific array elements (eg. $json['features'] or $json->features) and receive an error.

And here's the twist: if I copy the geoJSON from the console in Chrome and replace $tempData with it (IOW, text geojson) all works fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here is the output of`print_r($_POST)`:

```
     <pre>Array
 (
     [polygon] => "{\n  \"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\n  \"features\": [\n    {\n      \"type\": \"Feature\",\n      \"geometry\": {\n        \"type\": \"Polygon\",\n        \"coordinates\": [\n          [\n            [\n              -79.87384029097899,\n              43.95742561339064\n            ],\n            [\n              -80.05236812301024,\n              43.59649620245567\n            ],\n            [\n              -79.43988033004149,\n              43.64819092196166\n            ],\n            [\n              -79.87384029097899,\n              43.95742561339064\n            ]\n          ]\n        ]\n      },\n      \"properties\": {}\n    }\n  ]\n}"
     [u] => 339255ed-4a7e-XXXXXXXXXXX
     [i] => ###
 )
 </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

json_decode has an argument that accepts a bool parameter that will tell the json_decode function to decode as an object or an assoc array.

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

In your code you have set

`json_decode($tempData, true)`  This will decode as an array.

Set the 2nd parameter to false and it will output as an object.

`json_decode($tempData, false)`

See if that solves your problem.

Comment: Can you please do `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your page.  Can you also please post you javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to everything I had read on submitting the geoJSON using jQuery ajax, changing the `JSON.stringify(geoJsonInput.value)` to just `geoJsonInput.value` worked, and the output now looks like this:

```
     ARRAY Stuff:
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => -79.652869183496
             [1] => 44.020660503319
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => -79.777838665918
             [1] => 43.820846152094
         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [0] => -79.37546439834
             [1] => 43.83372569482
         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [0] => -79.652869183496
             [1] => 44.020660503319
         )

 )
 Set 1: -79.652869183496,44.020660503319
 Set 2: -79.777838665918,43.820846152094
 Set 3: -79.37546439834,43.83372569482
 Set 4: -79.652869183496,44.020660503319
```

Thanks all for your thoughts, and time.